# Field doesn't have default value upon factory seeding against a one to many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-seeding

I have one `speciality` that can have many `procedures`.

I am wanting to seed both the speciality with many procedures.

**Models:**

**Speciality**

```
class Speciality extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function procedures() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Procedure');
    }
}
```

**Procedure**

```
class Procedure extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['speciality_id', 'name'];

    public function speciality() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Speciality');
    }
}
```

---

**Factories:**

**Speciality**

```
$factory->define(App\Speciality::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => 'Example'
    ];
});
```

**Procedure**

```
$factory->define(App\Procedure::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->realText(20)
    ];
});
```

---

**Seeding:**

```
public function run()
    {
        factory(App\Speciality::class)->create()
            ->each(function($speciality) {
                $speciality->procedures()
                    ->saveMany(factory(App\Procedure::class, rand(5,20))
                    ->make()
                );
        });
    }
```

The error shown is:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'speciality_id' doesn't
>   have a default value (SQL: insert into `procedures` (`name`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (It means much the., 2018-04-17
>   19:09:31, 2018-04-17 19:09:31))

`speciality_id` isn't set as a value within the `procedure` factory, because it's the foreign key to the speciality. But my understanding of using `$speciality->procedures()` is it would automatically assign the speciality_id upon seeding.

Why is this error happening please. Many thanks.

Comment: check without using procedure factory like  ->saveMany([
    new Procedure(['name' => 'A new name'])
]);

Comment: if this works the problem is with your factory

Comment: Are models that you shown same in your code or simplified?

Comment: They're the same @Kyslik.

Comment: Your code works for me. Try debugging `HasOneOrMany::setForeignAttributesForCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here but I think there is just a small issue of when you call `make`:

```
public function run()
    {
        factory(App\Speciality::class)->create()
            ->each(function($speciality) {
                $speciality->procedures()
                    ->saveMany(factory(App\Procedure::class, rand(5,20))->make());     

        });
    }
```

Never used this with `saveMany()` before though, only `save()`, but try it out?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's throwing an error on the `->saveMany` line - `Call to a member function make() on integer`. It looks like the `->make()` should be outside the brackets? Which if it is, the error reappears.

Comment: @Ben what version are you using?

Comment: Latest 5.6. I have to keep typing to allow submission of comment!

Comment: @JoshRumbut I thought that there is a typo in OP, but its actually correct.

Comment: @Ben I messed up the parens, what I have now is working for me in my app, try it out

Comment: Thanks @JoshRumbut, unfortunately the same error still applies. What's different on yours than on mine ? :)

Comment: @Ben Did you get `member function make() on integer` error or the original error?

Comment: @Ben could you check that value of `$specialty` inside the `each` function?